# Text input hint onChange

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

I have a text input and I want to, sort of; auto complete the number typed by the user with `000..`

It needs to look like the picture below:

[image: Example of what I want]

When the user is still typing, add zeros to complete the number (it needs to have 6 digits).

But just as a hint/placeholder (like shown in the picutre above).

I tried using the placeholder attribute, but it will disappear as soon as the user starts typing. Plus... the value of the place holder is dynamic. It changes according the what the users type.

I hope my problem is clear.

Answer (score 5):

```js
        
        function myFunction() {

        var x = document.getElementById("number");
        x.value = parseInt(x.value, 10);// removes front trailing zeros
        x.value = pad(x.value, 6);//add front trailing zeros
        
    }
        
        function pad (str, max) {
          str = str.toString();
          str = str.length < max ? pad("0" + str, max) : str;
          return str;
        }
```

```html
   Enter your number: <input type="text" id="number" onkeyup="if(!(event.keyCode>36&&event.keyCode<41)){myFunction()}" onfocus="this.trailingZeros">
```

Comment: This does not let me navigate through the input with my arrow keys.

Answer (score 2):

This is how I would do it:

```
$(".mytext").on('keyup keypress change', function(e) {
  if ($(this).val().length >= 6) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
  $(".txtbg").text(Array(7 - $(this).val().length).join("0"))
});
```

[Here is the **JSFiddle demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/qzacq2n8/)

The question in particular did not tag JQuery, so consider this as an alternate solution.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm looking for. But I wish there's a way to make it really dynamic and in order to work for all devices (I'm using it for a mobile website). But I'll try to find a way to use the idea at least. Thank you for your help